# How to write a foreach loop statement in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm working in SAS as a novice. I have two datasets:

Dataset1

| Unique ID | ColumnA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 39 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |

Dataset2

| Unique ID | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 55 |
| 2 | 10 |

For each UniqueID, I want to subtract all values of ColumnB by each value of ColumnA. And I would like to create a NewColumn that is 1 anytime 1>ColumnB-Column >30. For the first row of Dataset 1, where UniqueID= 1, I would want SAS to go through all the rows in Dataset 2 that also have a UniqueID = 1 and determine if there is any rows in Dataset 2 where the difference between ColumnB and ColumnA is greater than 1 or less than 30. For the first row of Dataset 1 the NewColumn should be assigned a value of 1 because 40 - 15 = 25. For the second row of Dataset 1 the NewColumn should be assigned a value of 0 because 40 - 39 = 1 (which is not greater than 1). For the third row of Dataset 1, I again want SAS to go through every row of ColumnB in Dataset 2 that has the same UniqueID as in Dataset1, so 55 - 20 = 35 (which is greater than 30) but NewColumn would still be assigned a value of 1 because (moving to row 3 of Datatset 2 which has UniqueID =2) 20 - 10 = 10 which satisfies the if statement.

So I want my output to be:

| Unique ID | ColumnA | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 1 | 30 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 |

I have tried concatenating Dataset1 and Dataset2 into a FullDataset. Then I tried using a do loop statement but I can't figure out how to do the loop for each value of UniqueID. I tried using BY but that of course produces an error because that is only used for increments.

```
DATA FullDataset;
    set Dataset1 Dataset2; /*Concatenate datasets*/
        do i=ColumnB-ColumnA by UniqueID;
            if 1<ColumnB-ColumnA<30 then NewColumn=1;
         output;
        end;
    RUN;
```

I know I'm probably way off but any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You want to merge the two datasets, not set them together.  First sort each dataset by uniqueid using proc sort, then use "merge dataset1 dataset2; by uniqueid;" instead of "set dataset1 dataset2".  Then you won't need a do loop or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way that answers your question most directly is the keyed set.  This isn't necessarily how I'd do this, but it is fairly simple to understand (as opposed to a hash table, which is what I'd use, or a SQL join, probably what most people would use).  This does exactly what you say: grabs a row of `A`, says for each matching row of `B` check a condition. It requires having an index on the datasets (well, at least on the `B` dataset).

```
data colA(index=(id));
input ID ColumnA;
datalines;
1 15
1 39
2 20
3 10
;;;;

data colB(index=(id));
input ID    ColumnB;
datalines;
1 40
2 55
2 30
;;;;
run; 

data want;
  *base: the colA dataset - you want to iterate through that once per row;
  set colA;
  
  *now, loop while the check variable shows 0 (match found);
  do while (_iorc_ = 0);
    *bring in other dataset using ID as key;
    set colB key=ID ;
    * check to see if it matches your requirement, and also only check when _IORC_ is 0;
    if _IORC_ eq 0 and 1 lt ColumnB-ColumnA lt 30 then result=1;
    * This is just to show you what is going on, can remove;
    put _all_;
  end;
  
  *reset things for next pass;
  _ERROR_=0;
  _IORC_=0;
  
run;
```

Comment: I'm not getting any output column?

Comment: @OctoberFierce In `want` there is a column `result`, that is what you want I believe.